# error: resource mapping not found for name

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity: 
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes: 
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

File Name: pv.yml
Command: kubectl apply -f pv.yml

error: resource mapping not found for name: "task-pv-volume" namespace: "" from "pv.yml": no matches for kind "PersistentVolume" in version "apps/v1"
ensure CRDs are installed first

Please help me to fix this issue.

```
[cloudshell-user@ip-10-4-28-84 \~\]$ kubectl version
Client Version: v1.28.1-eks-43840fb
Kustomize Version: v5.0.4-0.20230601165947-6ce0bf390ce3
Server Version: v1.28.5-eks-5e0fdde
```

YML is not executing. Earlier it was working fine.

Comment: (You should almost never need to manually create a `PersistentVolume`, nor should you use a `hostPath` volume in most cases.  You tagged this with [tag:amazon-eks]: in this environment, the `hostPath` will access a directory from whichever node the Pod happens to be running on.  This can lead to inconsistent results between replicas, misplaced data if Pods are recreated on different nodes, and actual data loss if the cluster autoscaler deletes a Node with data on it.)

Comment: I tried --> apiVersion: v1

Still, It's not working.

Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "pv.yml": PersistentVolume in version "v1" cannot be handled as a PersistentVolume: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.acessModes"